# Documentation for aapt element in Ant script

Tags: android, ant, build, aapt

I'm working on some Ant scripts for an Android build system and have come across an element to call aapt.  I have seen lots of examples with

exec executable="${aapt}"

but the ones that come out of the main_rules.xml file use a different format

```
    <aapt executable="${aapt}"
            command="package"
            debug="${build.packaging.debug}"
            manifest="AndroidManifest.xml"
            assets="${asset.absolute.dir}"
            androidjar="${android.jar}"
            apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
            resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"
            resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}">
        <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
        <!-- <nocompress /> forces no compression on any files in assets or res/raw -->
        <!-- <nocompress extension="xml" /> forces no compression on specific file extensions in assets and res/raw -->
    </aapt>
```

I would like to rename the package using this element, but cannot find any documentation about how to use it.  Does anyone know where I can find some?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find anything and ended up using the following which seems to work

```
    <exec executable="${aapt}" failonerror="true">
      <arg value="package" />
      <arg value="-f" />
      <arg value="-v" />
      <arg value="-M" />
      <arg path="AndroidManifest.xml" />
      <arg value="-A" />
      <arg path="assets" />
      <arg value="-I" />
      <arg path="${android.jar}" />
      <arg value="-m" />
      <arg value="-J" />
      <arg path="${out.absolute.dir}" />
      <arg value="-F" />
      <arg path="${out.absolute.dir}/${resource.package.file.name}" />
      <arg value="-S" />
      <arg path="res" />
      <arg value="--rename-manifest-package" />
      <arg value="my.new.package.name" />
    </exec>
```

Answer (score 7):

In the new(er) version of the Android SDK, the ant build script works in a different way.
It does not directly invoke the *aapt* command via an `exec` element but rather defines 
an aapt task.
The latter one is implemented by the java class `com.android.ant.AaptExecTask`.
This class only provides a subset of the aapt command line options.

You can find a brief description of the mapping between aapt command line options and the ant parameters below as found in the source java doc:

```
Aapt Option             Ant Name        Type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
path to aapt            executable      attribute (Path)
command                 command         attribute (String)
-v                      verbose         attribute (boolean)
-f                      force           attribute (boolean)
-M AndroidManifest.xml  manifest        attribute (Path)
-I base-package         androidjar      attribute (Path)
-A asset-source-dir     assets          attribute (Path
-S resource-sources     <res path="">   nested element(s)
                                        with attribute (Path)
-0 extension            <nocompress extension="">  nested element(s)
                        <nocompress>               with attribute (String)
-F apk-file             apkfolder                  attribute (Path)  
                        outfolder                  attribute (Path) deprecated
                        apkbasename                attribute (String)
                        basename                   attribute (String) deprecated

-J R-file-dir       rfolder         attribute (Path)
                                    -m always enabled
```

As far as I found out, there is no way to provide the generic aapt options through this new build task. This seems to be possible only by taking a modified copy of the SDK's build.xml
with replacements for the aapt invocations.

If anyone knows a better solution, I'd be glad to read about, too ;-)

EDIT: In even newer versions of the SDK the introduced renaming packages again:

```
Aapt Option   --rename-manifest-package package-name 
Ant Name      manifestpackage
Type          attribute (String)
```

Comment: I find the attribute name of --rename-manifest-package option for long time. This is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt there is any documentation beyond the source code.

Comment: ... which can be found for example here: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.5/development/tools/anttasks/src/com/android/ant/AaptExecLoopTask.java