# Android Assets and NDK

Tags: android-ndk

I'm trying to read a simple text file from my native code.

1. I placed file.txt under assets folder
2. In my activity I'm creating asset manager: `assetManager = getAssets();`
   Then I'm passing the assetManager to my native method and(as in the native audio example):

   ```
   AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
   AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, "file.txt", AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
   AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);

   off_t start, length;

   int fd = AAsset_openFileDescriptor(asset, &start, &length);
   ```

The problem is that `fd` is smaller than 0!!!

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AAsset_openFileDescriptor` will work only with files that are not compressed (like mp3,jpg,png, etc...). It's written in documentation (asset_manager.h header file):

```
/**
 * Open a new file descriptor that can be used to read the asset data.
 *
 * Returns < 0 if direct fd access is not possible (for example, if the asset is
 * compressed).
 */
int AAsset_openFileDescriptor(AAsset* asset, off_t* outStart, off_t* outLength);
```

Use either `AAsset_read` or `AAsset_getBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks. So it compressed text file by default?

Comment: Sorry for recomennting but I realy need filedescriptor so what is the way using AAsset_read or AAsset_getBuffer to un compres the file?

Comment: apk file is zip file. So most of files it contains (including ones in assets subdirectory) are compressed. Only specific files like mp3, jpeg, png and few other are not compressed.

Comment: For compressed files you can not get file descriptor. If you are using ant task to build apk, then you can modify aapt build task to exculde files with specific extensions from compression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809651/documentation-for-aapt-element-in-ant-script Of course, then your apk file will be bigger.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to config the apk builder of eclipse?

Comment: if you have an .obj file for a model you will need to make sure to not be compressed, this happened to me as well