# FFMpeg command in android tutorial

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to write a android app that concats two videos

i tried the following code

```
    InputStream in=null;
    OutputStream os=null;
    String appFileDirectory = getFilesDir().getPath();
    final String executableFilePath = appFileDirectory + "/ffmpeg";
    final String input ="concat:/mnt/sdcard/input1.mpg|/mnt/sdcrad/input2.mpg";
    File executable=new File(executableFilePath);
    try {
        in = getAssets().open("ffmpeg");
        os = new FileOutputStream(executable);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                // outputStream.flush();
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    executable.setExecutable(true);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executableFilePath + "-i \""+ input + "\" -c copy /mnt/sdcrd/output.mpg");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

this code doesn't give any error or it is not crashing but nothing happens when i click the button. I created the ffmpeg build that is compatible with android. So can anyone help me out how to run the command from android java code.

Comment: i kept the ffmpeg executable file inside the assets folder of the project's root.

Answer (score 0):

Add some logs to check if the ffmpeg file is created, if it gets executable permissions, if /mnt/sdcard input files exist, if your app has permissions to read and write external storage.

One obvious error is that the input is on non-existent **sdcrad** and output tries to go to not-existent **sdcrd**, but these may be a problem of copy/paste to SO.

BTW, you can easily avoid the hassle of unpacking the executable from assets,  see my answer at [How to package native commandline application in apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383552/how-to-package-native-commandline-application-in-apk)