# Android binary executable file

Tags: android, android-ndk, kernel, ext4

I'm trying to push executable file to the phone, file was compiled by `NDK`.
But after copying files to the device they lost their permission (became no excecutable).

Is there any solution to fix kernel sources, or other sources in Android to fix this problem (lost permissions)? I'm pretty sure that it can be  `ext4` problem...

Note:
I don't want use `chmod` each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap your executable in an installable APK, here is the simple trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384650/192373. It has been tested to work up to JellyBean 4.3, but please be aware that it relies on some undocumented behaviours of the PackageManager.