# Android package manager only unpacks libxxx.so named libraries

Tags: android, java-native-interface, apk, native

I've made a jni library that dynamically loads plugins using dlopen, plugin library files have a different naming e.g. `zzz_abc.so`.

eclipse and ant are correctly bundling these files in the apk, but the android packagemanager only unpacks files named `libxxx.so`, other filename patterns are ignored, perhaps in debug, gdbserver is added and unpacked on my 4.1 phone (but not on 4.4 genymotion emulator).

There is something "magic" to control this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I've verified and unfortunately the native library installer only copies filenames like `libxxx.so` and `gdbserver`, if someone is interested the code is in [frameworks/base/core/jni/com_android_internal_content_NativeLibraryHelper.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/jni/com_android_internal_content_NativeLibraryHelper.cpp).

Comment: [Right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17384650/192373). The Package Manager on device looks for `^lib.+\.so$` pattern when it copies native libraries to `/data/data/your.package.name/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Android Package Manager copies libraries according to device processor architecture (armv7a, armv6, x86, mips). So if you use x86 based emulator, you need to provide x86 build of your library.

Comment: gdbserver is not copied because of a bug in genymotion 4.4 image, there is a patched `libandroid_runtime.so` around