# How do I make ndk-build create executable named like a library?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, android.mk

I want my native executable to be [auto-populated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384650/266720) to `/data/data/.../lib/`. For this it is to be named like `lib*.so`. But if I try to set this name, Android NDK complains:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libhello.so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

```
Android NDK: jni/Android.mk:hello.so: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME must not contain a file extension
```

Comment: possible duplicate: *[How to package native commandline application in apk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383552/how-to-package-native-commandline-application-in-apk)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround: install with a name Android NDK wants, then rename after installation:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

all:
        mv ${NDK_APP_DST_DIR}/hello ${NDK_APP_DST_DIR}/libhello.so
```

And your application can call the executable `/data/data/<package>/lib/libhello.so` without any preparatory steps.

Comment: This isn't a good practice. Somewhere else, there may be a different set of rules for `all`. Most likely not, because a convention is not to add rules to `all`. But still, the convention is there not to be broken unless necessary.

Comment: Furthermore, it is wrong to expect any `ndk-build` invocation to build `all` explicitly or implicitly. The correct approach is to add `libhello.so` to built modules list, and make sure it depends on `hello`, produced by `$(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)`.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to build an executable instead of a shared library. You want to change this:

```
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

to this:

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Yes, because of I want an executable that is callable by `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: @Vi The shared libraries can be executed (should they have a `main` entry point). I'm using a shared library for a daemon process and it executes.