# ABI specific android resource qualifier

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-resources

I am planning to use python code in my app. So I have to ship python binaries along with the app. I was planning to store the apks in the `raw` resource directory.

However since the apk size would be huge if I include all abi binaries in a single apk, I would like to do an abi based split on my apk. To do that I need an ABI specific android resource qualifier. Is there anything like that? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PackagingOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html) can be combined with ProductFlavors to achieve any level of flexibility, but this is not necessary to achieve your declared goal.

I invite you to use the trick that I [proposed a while agp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384650/192373). The bottom line is that if you put the executables in the expected directories under **jniLibs**, and give them funny names that start with **lib** and end with **.so**, Android build tools will happily pack them into your APK, and the installer will happily prepare them to be used according to the ABI.

This way, you can use the full power of [ABI-determined split](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split), as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, fake *.so libs under lib/ doesn't appear to work anymore. They aren't available in file system. /data/..../{app}/lib only contains real libraries. Something must have changed in the Android runtime.

Comment: It works out of box if you distribute apk. With aab you have to add `android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false` to `gradle.properties` file