# Android raw directory abi qualifier with app bundle?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-app-bundle, android-resource-qualifiers

I'd like to provide different raw files (which is essentially zip file and it's relatively large ~ 15Mb) dependent on ABI (armeabi-v7a/arm64-v8a) for Android application distributed as App Bundle. I can't see in [the doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) on how i can add ABI qualifier.

The workaround described in [similar QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50090548/1103561) (essentially mimic a shared library per ABI) is undesired as it will take a space on user device twice - as "shared library" and as extracted dir structure.

Another workaround: to pack both with a specific filename (eg. `myres_arm32` and `myres_arm64`) and add some runtime logic (smth similar to `if (is32Bit()) extract("myres_arm32") else extract("myres_arm64")`) to aab is undesired too as aab grows and has both inside (so it makes automatic splitting per ABI for AAB impossible).

The following does not work (files are just not found so `R.raw.myres` is  not declared):

```
|_raw
   |_arm64-v8a
   |   |__myres
   |_armeabi-v7a
       |__myres
```

Comment: Putting files in lib/ directory would be the only option today.